# Replacing values in data frame with another data frame based on one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have two dataframes, one that contains some information and a shorter dataframe that contains some amendments I want to make to the first. I have tried something similar to that written below.

```
for x in df['var']:
    if x in df2['var']:
         df['var2'] == df2['var2']
```

For example:

```
---> df
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8

---> df1
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
dog            4          0                  5
spider         8          0                  9

---> output
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  5
spider         8          0                  9
fish           0          0                  8
```

Comment: You will find quick help if you post samples of your dataframe and what you need the amended to look like. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks - I've added an example dataset

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  `df.update()`

```
df.update(df1)



        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon       2.0        2.0               10.0
dog          4.0        0.0                5.0
spider       8.0        0.0                9.0
fish         0.0        0.0                8.0
```

**Alternative**

```
import numpy as np
df[df.index.isin(df1.index)]=np.nan
df1.combine_first(df)
```

**How it works**

`#Find shared index between the two dataframes which are in df`.

```
df[df.index.isin(df1.index)]

#Make them NaN


df[df.index.isin(df1.index)]=np.nan

#Use [.combine_first][1] to fill them

df1.combine_first(df)
```

Comment: @anona Let me know how you go. Happy to help further

Comment: Is this helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had a go but I've found it is adding the observations to the list rather than updating them.